# Joomla 3.3 Unset CSS

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla3.0

I am having trouble getting a css style to unset. Here is what I have tried:

```
$BaseURL = $this->baseurl;
unset($this->_styleSheets[$BaseURL.'/media/com_namewithheld/css/style.css']);
unset($this->_styleSheets[JURI::root(true).'/media/com_namewithheld/css/style.css']);
```

neither works, I even tried using the entire sites url? What could be going wrong? All may other unsets are working fine.

Comment: Couple of questions: What exact version of Joomla are you using? and Where are you putting this code?

Comment: Put this code in a system plugin and order the plugins so your is the last.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn I would prefer not to have to write a separate plugin to unset something, seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If its the Joomla media folder you probably don't need the template part "com_namewithheld/"

```
$BaseURL = $this->baseurl;
unset($this->_styleSheets[$BaseURL.'/media/css/style.css']);
unset($this->_styleSheets[JURI::root(true).'/media/css/style.css']);
```

Some components force stylesheets and javascripts to be added, and the unset fails to work through the template.

The best ways I know are:

a) comment out the code: [a discussion i had on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788327/remove-hastip-javascript-code-from-joomla/12796087#12796087)

b) use a plugin: [JS CSS Control](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/20075) is my recommended usage

Plus if you decide to [cache](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/12088) your site - the cached version will ignore your template overrides and add your files - so I recommend plugin method.